# Could Firefox be automatically pre-loading html elements?

Tags: javascript, firefox, html-parsing

I have a JavaScript variable that holds an image tag surrounded by an anchor tag. Pretty normal stuff.

```
myvar="<a href='foo'><img src='bar'></a>";
```

What happens in Firefox, is that even though I'm *not* choosing to document.write the contents of that myvar variable, I nevertheless see that the image referenced by the IMG tag does actually get loaded. You'd never know it's happening without having a HTTP proxy tool running. I see in Fiddler that image being loaded. I don't see the image in the page of course, because I didn't choose to document.write the tag into the page.

Is Firefox trying to be too clever and not-so-intelligently parsing through the HTML page, even through the embedded JavaScript in the page, and seeing an IMG tag and pre-loading it? It's the only explanation I have.

I'd have tried breaking up the img tag if I could recreate it in a simple test page, but I can't. If anyone here tells me yes Firefox 4+ definitely does that, then I'll change it to something like

```
myvar="<"+"a href='foo'><i"+"mg src='bar'></"+"a>";.
```

It'll be sad to have to do that (or one of the many other alternatives) but it'll work.

Comment: AFAIK this should not happen. Are you sure you are not generating a DOM Element from the string at some point? Generating DOM Elements can happen in various ways, not only by dodcument.write. Setting innerHTML will create DOM Elements aswell as passing the string to the jQuery constructor, eg ``$(myvar)``.

Comment: I built a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AtrAp/) an tested it with FF6 (I do not have FF4 installed) and I cannot reproduce your behaviour. The image will only be loaded if the second line is uncommented.

Comment: I also cannot repro in FF6, have you tried with extensions disabled? (firefox -safe-mode) also could an initial rendering of that fragment associate the pages cache entry with the image?

Comment: I also can't recreate it on a simple test page, otherwise I would have figured it out. It's only on a client's page that it's happening, and they haven't even noticed. I was troubleshooting a different problem for them which is now resolved. Daniel, I'm definitely not creating a DOM element in any other way. I can't recreate this in FF5, IE, Safari, Opera or anything else. Just FF4. I see that FF4 despite being only 4 months old is already out of support (according to wikipedia). FF4 is declining rapidly: http://marketshare.hitslink.com/report.aspx?qprid=3&qpcustom=Firefox+4.0

Comment: I'm not going to worry about it for now. It's a small problem (the image is tiny and one of well over 300 elements on the client's page, yeah it's nasty). It's also a rapidly declining problem as FF4 fades away quickly. Plus I can't recreate it on any other pages. Time to stop worrying methinks.

Answer (score 1):

Is the JavaScript loaded from an external .js file or inlined in a script tag ? If inlined, you should make sure that it is not parsed as HTML content, instead declaring it as CDATA:

```
<script type="text/javascript">//<![CDATA[

// JS Stuff

//]]></script>
```

Comment: Wow, are browsers really not intelligent enough to do this themselves these days?

Comment: This is not a good suggestion. The CDATA hack was used to prevent browsers of the very first generation, like MOSAIC, which wheren't aware of the script tag, to render the JavaScript. All browsers since this first generation of browsers however are aware of the script tag, even if they do not parse and execute the scripts. You *DO NOT* need this construct, if you do not expect your website beeing visited by time travellers from the past.